# Chrome login auto dropdown is too big

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, autocomplete

I have strange problem with Google Chrome's autocomplete on login page on my website.
When there are many logins, the login/emails dropdown is so big, that it overlaps windows start menu.

I don't want to turn autocomplete off. If only there was a way to make it smaller or with scrollbar.
Is it possible?

I was searching the web for solution and strangely I haven't found any similar question. Only questions about disabling autocompletes completely or autocompletion of search results. Nothing about start-menu-overlapping too big logins autocomplete list.

**EDIT**

No custom javascript widget is used here. This is default Chrome's autocomplete mechanism.

[image: strange autocomplete behavior]

Comment: Can you ppos yor ode, what autocmplete widget are you using?

Comment: It's default Chrome autocomplete. No widget is used. I can delete those logins from the list with shift+delete while hovering over one of the items but I think it's not acceptable.

Comment: don't know if it will work but try wrapping the autocomplete list in a div with a max height and overflow-y:scroll, that should add a scrollbar and limit the size

Comment: I think it would be possible if I was using custom autocomplete widget that I coudl control some way. This is browser's default autocomplete which is even going out of browser window boundaries. Firefox for example has nice scrollbar inside his autocomplete.

Comment: how's the autocomplete getting so many names in the login field, are you filling it somehow ?

Comment: I have so many test accounts in my website and I just logged in once as each of them.

Answer (score 0):

set scrol bar...

```
.DropDown{
height: 60px;
max-height: 60px;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: it's an example i gave you hope it will help..:)

Comment: Sorry but this dropdown is not rendered in html so i don't have control over it. I added html and css to question tags because maybe there is some trick to style input tag somehow. But in your answer you assume that I can style the dropdown list in "DropDown" class as if it was  div element. But unfortunately it's not.

Comment: @Billy Actually this is not a very original idea, everyone who knows basic html/css would answer this. What makes you think that this is "your original genius idea"?